# LinkedIn products to subscribe to get access to messaging api

Tags: api, scope, linkedin-api

We are tech start-up developing an application and would like to utilise the messaging and connections api.
It looks like this would require special approval from you since the API documentation is saying "Usage of this API is restricted to approved partners, subject to limitations via API agreement."
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/communications/messages

We have added all the available products in the application dashboard but that seem to be not adding all the scopes we need to make these calls.
Could someone help us with the process of the product we need to have to get the correct permission so that we can access those APIs?

Thanks

Robi